# Vuetify checkbox with nested array as v-model not treated as array, no multi-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When setting a checkbox groups v-model to an array within a parent object, it is not being treated as an array, and instead a single field, resulting in a single select behavior instead of multi.

This is the behavior I am after: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/#model-as-array
Notice the checkboxes are bound to the array, allowing multi-select.

I would like to embed the v-model array to one within an object, but it is not being treated as an array, and I am only able to select 1 item.

```
<v-checkbox
  dense
  v-model="myobject.checkboxes"
  label="Label A"
  value="A"
></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox
  dense
  v-model="myobject.checkboxes"
  label="Label B"
  value="B"
></v-checkbox>

....

data() {
  return {
    myobject: {
      checkboxes:['A']
    },
    ...
  }
```

If I move `checkboxes` up a level, all works as expected, but it seems I should be able to consolidate into the parent object.

Comment: Displaying shows the currently selected value, which changes as a select different checks, as if checkboxes[] is a string.

Comment: Seems an outdated version of `myobject` (which are view preferences) that I restore from vuex on opening the page is over writing my definition in `data()`, after which `checkboxes` is no longer an array. Not sure the best approach to solve this. Thoughts?